# Função decode SQL aplicada DATAS

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou com uma dúvida preciso fazer um select onde preciso mostrar se o cadastro de um cliente está ativo ou não, no banco de dados fica tratado da seguinte maneira, tem um campo data de saida se o campo estiver em branco o cadastro está ativo agora se o cadastro estiver preenchido preciso mostrar que está inativo. Para fazer esse SQL como posso usar o função DECODE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supondo um campo DATE, duas soluções

```
1) DECODE(DATA_SAIDA,NULL,'ATIVO','INATIVO') STATUS

2) (CASE WHEN DATA_SAIDA IS NULL THEN 'ATIVO' ELSE 'INATIVO' END) STATUS
```

Answer (score 1):

A solução do motta funciona perfeitamente, mas você pode também utilizar a função NVL2. O código fica mais legível.

```
NVL2( string1, value_if_not_null, value_if_null )
```

Veja o link: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl2.php